# Convergence of Taylor series for smooth complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I will start with the context in which the question appears.

I have the followin PDE:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = i\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} $$
with initial condition.
$$f(x,0) = f_0(x) $$
$$f_0 :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$$
The initial condition is considered smooth.
$$f_0 \in C^\infty$$
If I want to write the solution of this PDE for some $t>0$ the Taylor series can be used as follows:
$$f(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\partial ^n f}{\partial t^n}(x,t=0) \frac{t^n}{n!}$$
I then replace the temporal derivatives using the PDE so I get the following formula:
$$f(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\partial ^{2n} f}{\partial x^{2n}}(x,t=0)  \frac{(it)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\partial ^{2n} f_0}{\partial x^{2n}}(x) \frac{(it)^n}{n!}$$
Now, based on the last formula, is there a theorem based on which the series converges to my solution for any smooth complex initial condition $f_0(x)$ and any value of $t>0$ ? I don't need the proof of it, the name of the theorem is enough for searching.

Similar questions that I found here but do not answer my question are:

[Convergence of Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788684/convergence-of-taylor-series)
but the function considered here has a singularity.

[Convergence of Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251845/convergence-of-taylor-series) but I don't necessarily have an upper bound for the derivatives.

Another way of formulating the question is if I start from a function that is  smooth, is this enough to imply that the Taylor series is convergent to it on the entire domain? If not, what restrictions are imposed on $f_0$ and/or $t$.

I know so far that the term $|(it)^n|<n!$ but I'm not sure how to handle the influence of the derivatives because I want to have this result for a general smooth complex function $f_0$. Also I know of the theorem regarding the limit of the reminder, but I haven't figured it out if it can be applied for any function $f_0$.

An personal attempt to solve this, but that I did not manage to work with, is if I consider the following restrictions:
$$\frac{\partial ^{2n} f_0}{\partial x^{2n}}(x)<n!$$
$$t<1$$
From those restrictions, I can compare my series with a power series with ratio $r<1$ which converges, so my series should to. However I'm not sure if it converges to the solution or something else.